# Modify attribute on a model based on the other attributes when it is added: model.clean method?

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to modify an attribute on a model based on the other attributes when it is added from the admin or elsewhere.

For example:

```
Model A: 
has FK to Model B
has FK to Model C

Model B: 
has FK to Model C
```

When I create a Model A, I choose a Model B so I'd like the FK to Model C to be set automatically based on the FK to Model C that already exists on Model B.

I found the `Model.clean` method (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) but it says that it is not invoked when you call your model’s save() method so when is it invoked? I am a bit confused about the purpose of this method then.

I tried the clean method and I was able to make it work after some issues but I am wondering whether that's the best way to do it?

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Why can't you use lookups?

Comment: @Beltiras What do you mean?

Comment: Foreign keys are used to trace relationships.  What is your usecase?

Comment: Yes they are. The problem is not how to get modelC. I know how to get it to set it on modelA (``modelA.modelC = modelA.modelB.modelC``) but the question is when/where I should do that so that if I add a modelA in the admin with just setting a modelB, modelC on the modelA will be automatically set to the same one modelB has. Sounds like my question is not very clear. Sorry about that.

Comment: With your clarification it sounds even more redundant to have the foreign key for C in A.

Comment: I know I could get the modelC from modelA with a query but I have my reasons to make a direct link between model A and model C.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A(models.Model):
    #your fields

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            # you can check for if C key is in arguments and
            # and set it if you need to.  This is for new
            # objects.
```